# Is there a word for a person who doesn't think the rules apply to him?

Tags: single-word-requests, pejorative-language, epithet-requests

I'm trying to write a letter to the editor of my local paper about their report of a man who doesn't think the rules apply to him.  Is there a word for this?  He's a bit of an egoist, demanding to speak at city council meetings after the public hearing portion of the meeting has been closed.

Comment: _Elitist_ is one.

Comment: _Arrogant_, _self-centered_, _egotistical_, _anarchist_ (or maybe not), _"above the law"_, etc.

Comment: "Is there a word for this?" Yeah, I would say _childish_.

Comment: Banker - Politician

Comment: Prospective criminal, soon-to-be jail resident?

Comment: Wannabe prisoner?

Comment: I went with "callow obstreperousness", but it seems there out to be something more concise.

Comment: Some people, not necessarily me, might consider that to sound a bit pretentious.

Comment: @jgbelacqua: no, I meant callow - he's not young, but acts childhishly.  Puerile would have worked as well.

Comment: My comment failed and I lost the text, so I could still go with something else.

Comment: Inconceivably insensitive wretched person.

Comment: I've marked jgbelacqua's summary answer as "the answer", although I still think there's a word out there to capture several of these words.  Scofflaw isn't quite it because it doesn't convey the self-importance sense, and because disregarding the proper order of a city council meeting to magnify your own importance isn't quite illegal.  I like contumacious, but it also doesn't really capture that egoist sense that needs to be included.  Presumptuous is pretty close, but it doesn't quite capture the disregard of the formal order.  Good answers all!  I'll keep an eye out for more good words.

Comment: is it "rebellions" ?

Comment: teenager springs to mind.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

For one-worders, I like @Robusto's "self-important" and @Nick's "presumptuous."

I'll add "inconsiderate," since I don't see that it's been added yet.

I've also described people with similar tendencies as "having an unjustified sense of entitlement," though I usually leave out "unjustified."

"scofflaw" is a fine word, but it's almost an archaic usage.  I just haven't heard it in non-facetious, non-ironic usage in USAmerican language. 
"bumptious" falls into this category as well.  Nothing wrong with the word, but not used much.   It can be used.  Maybe you'll use it and start a trend.  Of course then it might become a cliché .

"sociopath" is probably the correct diagnosis, and so has the advantage of being literally correct.  Probably a bit inflammatory (unless you mean to be inflammatory, in which case, have at it).

I don't feel "loose cannon" is correct here, unless the OP has a different sense of the person in question than I'm getting.   Usually a loose cannon is someone who is institutionally entrenched and whose character is endangering either the institution or those it comes it contact with.

Answer (score 23):

scofflaw : –noun
1.
a person who flouts the law, especially one who fails to pay fines owed.
2.
a person who flouts rules, conventions, or accepted practices.

http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/scofflaw

Comment: In my eyes, the connotation on *scofflaw* implies the *scofflaw* is villainous, not just ignorant of the law.

Comment: @puddingfox: I think that connotation is compatible with the question's description.

Comment: @puddingfox: it sounds to me that the person in question is well aware of the law, but pretends that it does not apply to him...

Comment: That doesn't sound right at all. He'd be a scofflaw if he were deliberately ignoring the civil or criminal law, but he's merely trying to bend parliamentary procedure.

Comment: Couldn't you simply use `scoff`: `treat with contemptuous disregard; "flout the rules"`

Comment: @LucasMcCoy "Scoffer".  That might be what I was looking for.  A "self-important scoffer".  Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

You could try *self-important*.

Answer (score 9):

Perhaps *bumptious* or *presumptuous*

Answer (score 4):

*Sociopath* could be a possibility.

Comment: ) I think you're right, though probably not the best thing to say in a letter.

Comment: had to say it for completeness :P

Comment: Ha - I think it *is* the best shorthand for the fellow, based on the description.

Comment: The definition of the word is probably fitting, although I think it would convey the wrong magnitude of severity.

Answer (score 4):

What—nobody thought of "pompous"?  [From Webster](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pompous):

> pompous - having or exhibiting self-importance : arrogant

Answer (score 3):

The word *renegade* comes to my mind.

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps not a single word, but a phrase: your man is *acting with impunity*. Quite literally; as if the laws of the meeting don't apply to him.

**Impunity**

> exemption or immunity from punishment
>   or recrimination

Comment: interesting.  I wonder if `impunity` can be modified to be a character quality, like "impunitous" or something.

Answer (score 2):

You can use *egocentric*, or *egocentristic*.

Answer (score 2):

How about

> Criminal

That would seem to fit the bill.

Answer (score 2):

A "Maverick" is someone who thinks the rules don't apply to them.

The lead character in the movie Top Gun probably earned his callsign "Maverick" by being a maverick. While I expect the term didn't originate in that movie, the phrase "God damn it, Maverick!" has certainly secured a place in populate culture.

Comment: The term predates Top Gun.

Answer (score 2):

Insensitive? Insensible? Callous, as in "callous disregard"?

Answer (score 2):

A common epithet in use for such a person, and which captures the exact attitude of self-aggrandisement, is ***God-almighty.***

OED defines them as one who poses or is regarded by others, chiefly derisively, as omnipotent.

Answer (score 2):

Deluded, entitled, overgrown spoilt brat.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. We strongly prefer answers which offer detailed explanations, with links to references as many be suitable. The [help center](http://english.stackexchange.com/help) will offer additional guidance on how to best use this site.

Answer (score 1):

He's a *loose cannon*:

> an unpredictable or uncontrolled
>   person who is likely to cause
>   unintentional damage.

-New Oxford American

> a person whose reckless behavior
>   endangers the efforts or welfare of
>   others.

-Dictionary.com

(My initial answer was going to be *[maverick](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/maverick)*, but this led me to *loose cannon* and I liked it better.)

Answer (score 1):

What about *misfit* since you said 'rules doesn't apply to him'?

Answer (score 0):

Or a (self-centered) eccentric ?

Does "eccentric" really have positive connotation?

> Nobody better encapsulates Google’s ambitions, its ethics, and its worldview. At the same time, Page can be **eccentric, arrogant, and secretive**. Under his leadership, the company will be even harder to predict.

From [Wired](http://www.wired.com/magazine/2011/03/mf_larrypage/all/1)

Comment: "eccentric" usually has a sense of being benign, and might not be sufficiently critical for this case.

Comment: Yeah - it's kindof a euphemism for _weird_.  (_Euphemism_ implying that it's not a negative word)

Comment: @jgelacqua, "eccentric" doesn't **always** have such connotation. Please see the quote from Wired.

Comment: even in that case, "eccentric" is used to highlight unpredictability, not as a negative label in itself.  In business terms, Page's eccentricity is part of a set of characteristics which the writer doesn't expect to be entirely benign.  He could also be a sky-diver and rock climber -- not negative, but negative if you're looking for someone safe and predictable.

Answer (score 0):

How about *Rebel*? Rebels resist convention.

Comment: Hmm.  I think this typically has a slightly positive connotation.  (E.g, James Dean in *Rebel Without a Cause*.)  It's not a compliment, but seems akin to "swashbuckling" in many usages.  I usually hear it now used facetiously, as a dig on someone's barely-there or merely slight deviation from a typical convention (like adding honey instead of the office-supplied sugar to one's office coffee -- "Sam, you're *such* a rebel").

Comment: I would go even farther as to say that it _is_ a compliment.

Comment: I agree about the positive connotation part. Thanks @jgbe :)

Comment: Rebel is certainly not always positive, it is only positive to one side.

Comment: Why are all the people so adamant on down voting this one? Should I remove this answer?

Answer (score 0):

I like *[recalcitrant](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/recalcitrant)* and *[contumacious](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/contumacious)*, but then I'm addicted to syllables.

Comment: If someone is recalcitrant, he is resisting against something that is being imposed upon him, or unwilling to do something. This is not the case here. A general law or convention exists and he goes deliberately against it. He is not "resisting" so much as "violating", which is different.

Answer (score 0):

I kind of like "self-important gadfly", but that's just me. "Gadfly" can have positive connotations when not qualified.

Answer (score 0):

May be a bit extreme but: *psychopath* or *megalomaniac*

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps **solipsist** might work here?

Answer (score -1):

What about just *selfish*?  He certainly seems so.

Answer (score -2):

How about *prima donna*, one who thinks the rules apply to others and not them.

Comment: Could you include a definition or an excerpt which will back up your answer?