# Synonyms for "Almighty"

Tags: meaning, word-choice, synonyms, word-usage

- What is a perfect synonym for *Almighty*?
- For whom we could we use *Almighty*?
- Can *Almighty* be used for *God*?

Comment: Do you mean replacements for 'Almighty' as a supreme being specifically the Judeo-Christian-Muslim one, or as an all powerful entity possibly religious with not particular cultural connections, or the particular JCM god but having the specific power requirements in the name, or something else?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

First of all some people question the existence of *perfect* [synonyms](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synonym):

> Some lexicographers claim that no synonyms have exactly the same meaning (in all contexts or social levels of language) because etymology, orthography, phonic qualities, ambiguous meanings, usage, etc. make them unique. Different words that are similar in meaning usually differ for a reason: feline is more formal than cat; long and extended are only synonyms in one usage and not in others (for example, a long arm is not the same as an extended arm).

So, the context is important, and now, for the **Almighty**, yes its primary meaning according to [AHD](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/almighty) is

> **Almighty**, n.
>
> God. Used with *the*.

However, do not forget how strong and different is the context of religion and how the word **God** is in this sense overloaded with different meanings.

From [Wordnet](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/God+Almighty) you have

> Noun   1. **God Almighty** - terms referring to the Judeo-Christian God

So, yes, in context of Judeo-Christianism at least, **the Almighty** is synonym with **the God**. For other religious contexts you might want to see an article on [Names of God](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Names_of_God).

EDIT:
As for usage, the [Almighty](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=almighty) means God, however if you use it as adjective, as in (very well known) example:

> The almighty dollar, that great object of universal devotion throughout our land." [Washington Irving, 1836]

the meaning is metaphorical, so it still means god-like, divine. So, the question is what kind of usage are you talking about?

Comment: your first paragraph should be included automatically as a disclaimer to any question about synonyms :-)

Comment: +1 because I'm one of those who think the concept of 'perfect synonyms' is actually *counterproductive*, not just useless. If any such pair of words exist, they will rapidly diverge in connotations, if not precise definitions. Which then becomes contentious, because for some time the exact nature of that ongoing divergence becomes a matter of dispute for people wishing to argue for *their* understanding of the currently-fluid meanings, while others are moving in different directions while we wait for a concensus to emerge.

Comment: Related example of non-deity use https://english.stackexchange.com/a/137632/4915

Answer (score 3):

Remember, there are two uses of the word almighty.

As an adjective, it can be used with anything. An almighty racket, an almighty mess, an almighty wizard and indeed an almighty god (note the use of lower case).

The Almighty is a proper noun, specifically referring to the Judeo-Christian God.

Answer (score 2):

1)From the top of my head - omnipotent and all-powerful.

[This dictionary](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-synonyms/almighty) gives several rather interesting synonyms, I sure wouldn't thought of.

> 1 absolute, all-powerful, invincible, omnipotent, supreme, unlimited 
>   2  (informal) awful, desperate, enormous, excessive, great, intense, loud, severe, terrible

Yes, "Unlimited powaaaaah!"

2)Examples in [YourDictionary](http://sentence.yourdictionary.com/almighty) suggest, that almighty can be used with pretty everything, that can be one of the above words.

3)Apparently so.

Comment: You can certainly have an 'almighty screw up'

Comment: I like "unwimited powaaaah!" better.  It sounds like Elmer Fudd, or the Roman of Vulgar Appellation in Life of Brian: "Swike him, Centewion, vewey, woughly!"  And lest we forget, the Princess Bride: "Mawwage! Mawwage is what bwings us togethah today!"

Answer (score 2):

"Almighty" can refer to God if used in this way:

> **God Almighty**

"Almighty" has a very limited use because not a lot of people are actually "Almighty".

The perfect synonyms for Almighty also have to do with Deity:

> **Sovereign**
>
> **Omnipotent**

Answer (score 1):

On 2: Kaiser Wilhelm called himself "All-Highest", which I believe in German is very similar to almighty. 
On 3: "almighty" is an ordinary adjective. "Almighty", and particularly "the Almighty" refer only to God.